# array('_forced_secure' => true) in every page

Tags: magento-1.9, error, ssl, secure

In every page of my magento shop

there is a message

array('_forced_secure' => true)

[image]

Comment: enable template path hint from admin and check from where its coming

Comment: nothing happens i search it no array('_forced_secure' => true)

Comment: it is something php code you won't find easily check in 1column.phtml and all layout files this code would be in <pre> tag

Comment: okay sure but how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this array come from some phtml file and may be from `1column.phtml` or something kind of file

and as from its structure this variable should be in `<pre>` tag please check it your layout.phtml files